# Scala predicate composition

Tags: scala

The java Predicate interface provides an `or` method that is used to combine multiple predicates. Example:

```
Predicate<Integer> p1;
Predicate<Integer> p2;

Predicate<Integer> p2 = p1.or(p2)
```

Since scala does not have the `Predicate` interface but uses `Function1[A, Boolean]` for this purpose what would be the best way to write this? Preferably without the use of external libraries.

I try to avoid the following:

```
val p1: (A => Boolean)
val p2: (A => Boolean)

val p3: (A => Boolean) = (a => p1(a) || p2(a))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide an implicit conversion from `A ⇒ Boolean` to `Predicate` which supports the operations you want. Something like this:

```
implicit class Predicate[A](val p: A ⇒ Boolean) extends AnyVal {
  type Predicate[A] = A ⇒ Boolean

  def unary_!                     = (a: A) ⇒ !p(a)

  def ==[B >: A](x: Predicate[B]) = (a: A) ⇒ p(a) == x(a)
  def !=[B >: A](x: Predicate[B]) = (a: A) ⇒ p(a) != x(a)
  def ||[B >: A](x: Predicate[B]) = (a: A) ⇒ p(a) || x(a)
  def &&[B >: A](x: Predicate[B]) = (a: A) ⇒ p(a) && x(a)

  def  ^[B >: A](x: Predicate[B]) = (a: A) ⇒ p(a)  ^ x(a)
  def  |[B >: A](x: Predicate[B]) = (a: A) ⇒ p(a)  | x(a)
  def  &[B >: A](x: Predicate[B]) = (a: A) ⇒ p(a)  & x(a)
}
```

This implements all the methods available in `Boolean` with the same semantics, e.g. `Predicate.&&` will only evaluate the second predicate if the first evaluates to `true`, whereas `Predicate.|` will always evaluate both predicates.

Comment: Note: I started writing this answer before [@Joel Berkeley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55430826/2988) appeared, then got side-tracked. I'm posting it here for completeness' sake.

Comment: i tried to work out some way of abstracting all these methods, as they're all the same except `||`, `&&`, `^` etc, but to no avail. do you think it's possible?

Comment: @JoelBerkeley: Should be possible with a macro. But, that's beyond my capabilities.

Answer (score 10):

You could provide the `Predicate` functionality in an implicit value class as

```
implicit class Predicate[A](val p1: A => Boolean) extends AnyVal {
  def or[B >: A](p2: B => Boolean) = (a: A) => p1(a) || p2(a)
}
```

and then do

```
val gtOne = (x: Int) => x > 1
val ltMinusOne = (x: Int) => x < -1

val absGtOne = gtOne or ltMinusOne

absGtOne(-2)  // true
absGtOne(0)  // false
absGtOne(2)  // true
```

Comment: I would then make `Predicate` a value-class by extending `AnyVal` in order to avoid useless allocations.

Comment: @francoisr nice, hadn't come across value classes before

Answer (score 2):

It's not part of the standard library, but if you only need simple expressions, you could:

1. Use the Java version, possibly using extension methods for syntactic sugar like `p1 || p2` instead of `p1.or(p2)`.
2. Roll your own `case class Predicate[-A](p: A => Boolean)` with a few simple methods like:

   `def ||[B <: A](other: Predicate[B]): Predicate[B] = ???`

Answer (score 0):

My stateful predicate:

```
  /**
  * Predicate logic with the state to print the function in natural language
  */
object StatefulPredicate {

class Predicate[E, T](predicate: E => T => Boolean, e: E, chain: Option[(Operator, Predicate[E, T])] = None) {
    def test(t: T): Boolean = chain.map(c => c._1.execute(t, c._2.test(t), predicate(e))).getOrElse(predicate(e)(t))
    def and(e: E): Predicate[E, T] = new Predicate[E, T](this.predicate, e, Some(AND, this))
    def or(e: E): Predicate[E, T] = new Predicate[E, T](this.predicate, e, Some(OR, this))
    override def toString: String = chain.map(c => c._2.toString + " " + c._1.toString + " " + e.toString).getOrElse(e.toString)
  }

  sealed trait Operator {
    def execute[T](t: T, op1: Boolean, op2: T => Boolean): Boolean
  }

  case object AND extends Operator {
    override def execute[T](t: T, op1: Boolean, op2: T => Boolean): Boolean = op1 && op2(t)
    override def toString: String = "and"
  }

  case object OR extends Operator {
    override def execute[T](t: T, op1: Boolean, op2: T => Boolean): Boolean = op1 || op2(t)
    override def toString: String = "or"
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val p1: Predicate[Int, Seq[Int]] = new Predicate(e => s => s.contains(e), 10)
        val p2: Predicate[Int, Seq[Int]] = p1.or(25)
        val p3: Predicate[Int, Seq[Int]] = p2.and(25)
        val p4: Predicate[Int, Seq[Int]] = p3.and(40)
        print(p4.test(Seq[Int](10, 20, 30, 40)))
  }
}
```